# How does Flexible Search query translate to SQL query in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

As far as I know, Hybris uses FlexibleSearchQuery to query data. So to query the database, I need to translate FlexibleSearchQuery into SQL. I still do not know how Hybris does it.Can you help me understand?

I have stack trace code as follows:

I see: TranslatedQuery tQuery(class: FlexibleSearch method: executeSearch) = this.cacheKey.tq (class: FlexibleSearchCacheUnit method: compute).

So, Where does this.cacheKey.tq value come from?

```
PreparedStatementImpl   executeQuery

public ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException {
        if (this.isLoggingActivated()) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            ResultSet var5;
            try {
                var5 = this.wrapResultSet(this.prepStmtPassthru.executeQuery());
            } catch (SQLException var9) {
                this.getConnection().notifyError(var9);
                this.getConnection().logError(var9, "error executing query");
                throw var9;
            } finally {
                this.connection.getDataSource().getLogUtils().logElapsed(Thread.currentThread().getId(), this.connection.getConnectionID(), startTime, "statement", this.preparedQueryWithoutStackTrace, this.assembleQueryFromPreparedStatement());
            }

            return var5;
        } else {
            try {
                return this.wrapResultSet(this.prepStmtPassthru.executeQuery());
            } catch (SQLException var11) {
                this.getConnection().notifyError(var11);
                this.getConnection().logError(var11, "error executing query");
                throw var11;
            }
        }
    }

FlexibleSearchExecutor  execute

public SearchResult execute(int start, int count, boolean dontNeedTotal, TranslatedQuery translatedQuery, List<Class<?>> resultClasses, Map values, PK languagePK, int prefetchSize, Set<PK> prefetchLanguages) {
        ConversionMetaInformation conversionResult = this.convertResultClasses(resultClasses);
        ExecutableQuery executableQuery = this.getExecutableQuery(translatedQuery, values, languagePK);
        JDBCValueMappings jdbcVM = JDBCValueMappings.getInstance();
        LimitStatementBuilder limitBuilder = this.limitStatementFactory.getLimitStatementBuilder(executableQuery, start, count);
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String query = null;

        SearchResult result;
        try {
            String errorMessageSecondPart;
            try {
                connection = this.tenant.getDataSource().getConnection();
                if (this.isNeedTotalAndCountIsZero(count, dontNeedTotal)) {
                    int totalCount = jdbcVM.getTotalCountFromCountQuery(connection, executableQuery.getCountSQL(), executableQuery.getCountValueList());
                    result = SQLSearchResultFactory.createCountOnlyResult(totalCount, start, count, executableQuery.getSQL(), executableQuery.getValueList());
                } else {
                    query = limitBuilder.getModifiedStatement();
                    statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    jdbcVM.fillStatement(statement, limitBuilder.getModifiedStatementValues());
                    long t1 = 0L;
                    long t2 = 0L;
                    long t3 = 0L;
                    long t4 = 0L;
                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }

                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }

                    int _start = limitBuilder.getOriginalStart();
                    int _count = limitBuilder.getOriginalCount();
                    if (limitBuilder.hasDbEngineLimitSupport()) {
                        _start = 0;
                        _count = -1;
                    }

                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }

                    RowFetchResult rowFetchResult = jdbcVM.getQueryResults(resultSet, conversionResult.getConvertedClasses(), _start, _count);
                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }

                    int totalCount = dontNeedTotal ? rowFetchResult.rows.size() : jdbcVM.getTotalCount(resultSet, rowFetchResult, start, count, connection, executableQuery, limitBuilder.hasDbEngineLimitSupport());
                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        LOG.debug(this.getInfoForLogging(executableQuery.getSQL(), limitBuilder.getModifiedStatement(), conversionResult.getConvertedClasses(), executableQuery.getValueList(), ", original range=[" + limitBuilder.getOriginalStart() + "," + limitBuilder.getOriginalCount() + "], rowcount=" + totalCount + ", query=" + (t2 - t1) / 1000L + "ms, fetch=" + (t4 - t3) / 1000L + "ms"));
                    }

                    result = SQLSearchResultFactory.createCacheable(new CacheableResultHolder(rowFetchResult, prefetchSize, prefetchLanguages, conversionResult), totalCount, start, count, limitBuilder.getModifiedStatement(), executableQuery.getValueList());
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException var35) {
                errorMessageSecondPart = Config.getBoolean("flexible.search.exception.show.query.details", false) ? var35.getMessage() + " query = '" + executableQuery.getSQL() + "', values = " + executableQuery.getValueList() : "enable the property 'flexible.search.exception.show.query.details' for more details";
                throw new FlexibleSearchException(var35, "wrong flexible search parameter - " + errorMessageSecondPart, 0);
            } catch (SQLException var36) {
                errorMessageSecondPart = Config.getBoolean("flexible.search.exception.show.query.details", false) ? var36.getMessage() + " query = '" + query + "', values = " + executableQuery.getValueList() : "enable the property 'flexible.search.exception.show.query.details' for more details";
                throw new FlexibleSearchException(var36, "SQL search error - " + errorMessageSecondPart, 0);
            }
        } finally {
            Utilities.tryToCloseJDBC(connection, statement, resultSet);
        }

        return result;
    }

FlexibleSearch  executeSearch

protected SearchResult executeSearch(TranslatedQuery tQuery, Map values, PK langPK, List<Class<?>> resultClasses, boolean dontNeedTotal, int start, int count, int prefetchSize, Set<PK> prefetchLanguages, boolean doExecuteQuery) throws FlexibleSearchException {
        return doExecuteQuery ? this.fsExecutor.execute(start, count, dontNeedTotal, tQuery, resultClasses, values, langPK, prefetchSize, prefetchLanguages) : this.fsExecutor.simulate(start, count, tQuery, values, langPK);
    }

FlexibleSearchCacheUnit compute

public final Object compute() throws FlexibleSearchException {
        this.usedCachedResult = false;
        StandardSearchResult ret = (StandardSearchResult)this.fs.executeSearch(this.cacheKey.tq, this.values, this.cacheKey.langPK, Arrays.asList(this.cacheKey.resultClasses), this.cacheKey.hasModifier(1), this.cacheKey.start, this.cacheKey.count, this.prefetchSize, this.prefetchLanguages, this.cacheKey.hasModifier(2));
        ret.setUnitHash(System.identityHashCode(this));
        return ret;
    }

AbstractCacheUnit   privateGetNoLock

private final Object privateGetNoLock() throws Exception {
        Object ret = this.value;
        if (this.isValueUnknown(ret)) {
            ret = this.compute();
            this.value = ret;
        }

        return ret;
    }

AbstractCacheUnit   privateGet

private final Object privateGet() throws Exception {
        return this.getTransactionAwareCache().isForceExclusiveComputation(this) ? this.privateGetSynchronized() : this.privateGetNoLock();
    }

AbstractCacheUnit   get

public final Object get() throws Exception {
        if (!this.useCache()) {
            return this.computeUncached();
        } else {
            TransactionAwareCache transactionAwareCache = this.getTransactionAwareCache();
            boolean success = false;
            AbstractCacheUnit valueUnit = transactionAwareCache.getOrAddUnit(this);
            Object ret = valueUnit.value;

            try {
                ret = this.isValueUnknown(ret) ? valueUnit.privateGet() : ret;
                success = true;
            } catch (CacheValueLoadException var9) {
                if (var9.getCause() instanceof Exception) {
                    throw (Exception)var9.getCause();
                }

                throw var9;
            } finally {
                if (!success) {
                    transactionAwareCache.removeUnit(valueUnit);
                }

            }

            return ret;
        }
    }

FlexibleSearchCacheUnit myGet

public final StandardSearchResult myGet() throws Exception {
        StandardSearchResult ret = (StandardSearchResult)this.get();
        ret.setFromCache(this.usedCachedResult);
        return ret;
    }

FlexibleSearch  search

public SearchResult search(SessionContext _ctx, String query, Map values, List resultClasses, boolean failOnUnknownFields, boolean dontNeedTotal, int start, int count) throws FlexibleSearchException {
        TranslatedQuery tQuery = null;
        int prefetchSize = this.getSearchPrefetchSize(_ctx);
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug(this.getSearchDebug(_ctx, query, resultClasses, failOnUnknownFields, dontNeedTotal, start, count, prefetchSize));
        }

        boolean doExecuteQuery = !this.disableExecution(_ctx);
        SessionContext localCtx = null;

        SearchResult var22;
        try {
            if (_ctx != null) {
                localCtx = JaloSession.getCurrentSession(this.getTenant()).createLocalSessionContext(_ctx);
                localCtx.setAttribute("disableExecution", Boolean.FALSE);
            }

            PK langPK = this.getSearchLangPK(localCtx);
            tQuery = this.translate(localCtx, this.getRestrictionPrincipal(localCtx), query, values != null ? values.size() : 0, langPK != null, failOnUnknownFields, this.disableRestrictions(localCtx), this.disablePrincipalGroupRestrictions(localCtx), values);
            Map _values = tQuery.removeUnusedValues(this.translatePathValueKeys(localCtx, tQuery.getValueKeys(), new CaseInsensitiveParameterMap(values != null ? values : Collections.EMPTY_MAP)));
            Set<PK> queryTCs = tQuery.getTypePKs();
            Set<Integer> beanTCs = new HashSet(queryTCs.size() * 4);
            PersistenceManager pm = this.getTenant().getPersistenceManager();
            Iterator var19 = queryTCs.iterator();

            while(var19.hasNext()) {
                PK typePK = (PK)var19.next();
                beanTCs.addAll(pm.getBeanTypeCodes(typePK));
            }

            if (beanTCs.isEmpty()) {
                throw new JaloInvalidParameterException("empty bean typcode list ( typePKs = " + tQuery.getTypePKs() + ", query = " + tQuery.getSQLTemplate() + " )", 0);
            }

            try {
                if (!this.isCachingDisabled(localCtx)) {
                    int ttl = this.getTTL(localCtx);
                    FlexibleSearch.FlexibleSearchCacheKey cacheKey = this.createCacheKey(resultClasses, dontNeedTotal, start, count, tQuery, doExecuteQuery, langPK, _values, beanTCs, ttl);
                    FlexibleSearchCacheUnit cacheUnit = this.createCacheUnit(prefetchSize, WrapperFactory.getPrefetchLanguages(localCtx), _values, cacheKey);
                    var22 = this.wrapSearchResult(cacheUnit.myGet());
                    return var22;
                }

                var22 = this.wrapSearchResult(this.executeSearch(tQuery, _values, langPK, resultClasses, dontNeedTotal, start, count, prefetchSize, WrapperFactory.getPrefetchLanguages(localCtx), doExecuteQuery));
            } catch (FlexibleSearchException var28) {
                throw var28;
            } catch (Exception var29) {
                throw new FlexibleSearchException(var29, var29.getMessage(), 0);
            }
        } catch (FlexibleSearchException var30) {
            LOG.error("Flexible search error occured...");
            if (tQuery == null) {
                LOG.error("Query translation was not successful.");
            }

            throw var30;
        } catch (JaloItemNotFoundException var31) {
            throw new JaloInternalException(var31, "cannot get type by translated query type pk", 0);
        } finally {
            if (localCtx != null) {
                JaloSession.getCurrentSession(this.getTenant()).removeLocalSessionContext();
            }

        }

        return var22;
    }

FlexibleSearch  search

public SearchResult search(String query, Map values, List resultClasses, boolean failOnUnknownFields, boolean dontNeedTotal, int start, int count) throws FlexibleSearchException {
        return this.search(JaloSession.hasCurrentSession() ? this.getSession().getSessionContext() : null, query, values, resultClasses, failOnUnknownFields, dontNeedTotal, start, count);
    }

DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2  execute

    private <T> de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult<T> getJaloResult(final FlexibleSearchQuery query) {
        return (de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult)this.getSessionService().executeInLocalView(new SessionExecutionBody() {
            public de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult<T> execute() {
                DefaultFlexibleSearchService.this.getQueryPreprocessorRegistry().executeAllPreprocessors(query);
                Map queryParams = (Map)DefaultFlexibleSearchService.this.toPersistenceLayer(query.getQueryParameters());

                try {
                    return FlexibleSearch.getInstance().search(query.getQuery(), queryParams, this.convertModelClassList(query), query.isFailOnUnknownFields(), !query.isNeedTotal(), query.getStart(), query.getCount());
                } catch (FlexibleSearchException var3) {
                    throw new de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException(var3.getMessage(), var3);
                }
            }

            private List<Class> convertModelClassList(FlexibleSearchQuery queryx) {
                List<Class> resultClassList = new ArrayList(queryx.getResultClassList().size());
                Iterator var4 = queryx.getResultClassList().iterator();

                while(var4.hasNext()) {
                    Class modelClass = (Class)var4.next();
                    resultClassList.add(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.this.getModelService().getModelTypeClass(modelClass));
                }

                return resultClassList;
            }
        });
    }

DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2  execute



DefaultSessionService   executeInLocalView

public Object executeInLocalView(SessionExecutionBody body) {
        Object var3;
        try {
            this.getOrCreateCurrentJaloSession().createLocalSessionContext();
            var3 = body.execute();
        } finally {
            this.getOrCreateCurrentJaloSession().removeLocalSessionContext();
        }

        return var3;
    }

DefaultFlexibleSearchService    getJaloResult

private <T> de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult<T> getJaloResult(final FlexibleSearchQuery query) {
        return (de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult)this.getSessionService().executeInLocalView(new SessionExecutionBody() {
            public de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult<T> execute() {
                DefaultFlexibleSearchService.this.getQueryPreprocessorRegistry().executeAllPreprocessors(query);
                Map queryParams = (Map)DefaultFlexibleSearchService.this.toPersistenceLayer(query.getQueryParameters());

                try {
                    return FlexibleSearch.getInstance().search(query.getQuery(), queryParams, this.convertModelClassList(query), query.isFailOnUnknownFields(), !query.isNeedTotal(), query.getStart(), query.getCount());
                } catch (FlexibleSearchException var3) {
                    throw new de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException(var3.getMessage(), var3);
                }
            }

            private List<Class> convertModelClassList(FlexibleSearchQuery queryx) {
                List<Class> resultClassList = new ArrayList(queryx.getResultClassList().size());
                Iterator var4 = queryx.getResultClassList().iterator();

                while(var4.hasNext()) {
                    Class modelClass = (Class)var4.next();
                    resultClassList.add(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.this.getModelService().getModelTypeClass(modelClass));
                }

                return resultClassList;
            }
        });
    }

DefaultFlexibleSearchService    search

public <T> SearchResult<T> search(FlexibleSearchQuery query) {
        ServicesUtil.validateParameterNotNull(query, "The 'query' is null!");
        de.hybris.platform.jalo.SearchResult<T> jaloResult = this.getJaloResult(query);
        if (jaloResult.getCount() == 0) {
            return this.createEmptyResult(jaloResult);
        } else {
            return jaloResult instanceof StandardSearchResult ? this.wrapOrConvert(query, (StandardSearchResult)jaloResult, () -> {
                return this.convert(jaloResult);
            }) : this.convert(jaloResult);
        }
    }

DefaultPagedFlexibleSearchService   search

public <T> SearchPageData<T> search(final String query, final Map<String, ?> queryParams, final PageableData pageableData)
    {
        validateParameterNotNull(query, "query cannot be null");
        validateParameterNotNull(pageableData, "pageableData cannot be null");
        Assert.isTrue(pageableData.getCurrentPage() >= 0, "pageableData current page must be zero or greater");
        Assert.isTrue(pageableData.getPageSize() > 0, "pageableData page size must be greater than zero");

        final FlexibleSearchQuery searchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
        if (queryParams != null && !queryParams.isEmpty())
        {
            searchQuery.addQueryParameters(queryParams);
        }

        searchQuery.setNeedTotal(true);
        searchQuery.setStart(pageableData.getCurrentPage() * pageableData.getPageSize());
        searchQuery.setCount(pageableData.getPageSize());

        final SearchResult<T> searchResult = getFlexibleSearchService().search(searchQuery);

        // Create the paged search result
        final SearchPageData<T> result = createSearchPageData();
        result.setResults(searchResult.getResult());
        result.setPagination(createPagination(pageableData, searchResult));
        // Note: does not set sorts

        return result;
    }

DefaultPagedFlexibleSearchService   search

public <T> SearchPageData<T> search(final List<SortQueryData> sortQueries, final String defaultSortCode,
            final Map<String, ?> queryParams, final PageableData pageableData)
    {
        validateParameterNotNull(sortQueries, "sortQueries cannot be null");
        validateParameterNotNull(defaultSortCode, "defaultSortCode cannot be null");
        validateParameterNotNull(pageableData, "pageableData cannot be null");
        Assert.isTrue(!sortQueries.isEmpty(), "sortQueries must not be empty");
        Assert.isTrue(pageableData.getCurrentPage() >= 0, "pageableData current page must be zero or greater");
        Assert.isTrue(pageableData.getPageSize() > 0, "pageableData page size must be greater than zero");

        // Work out which sort and query to use
        final SortQueryData selectedSortQuery = findSortQueryData(sortQueries, pageableData.getSort(), defaultSortCode);

        // Execute the query
        final SearchPageData<T> searchPageData = search(selectedSortQuery.getQuery(), queryParams, pageableData);

        // Specify which sort was used
        searchPageData.getPagination().setSort(selectedSortQuery.getSortCode());
        searchPageData.setSorts(createSorts(sortQueries, selectedSortQuery.getSortCode()));
        return searchPageData;
    }

DefaultCustomerAccountDao   findOrdersByCustomerAndStore

public SearchPageData<OrderModel> findOrdersByCustomerAndStore(final CustomerModel customerModel, final BaseStoreModel store,
            final OrderStatus[] status, final PageableData pageableData)
    {
        validateParameterNotNull(customerModel, "Customer must not be null");
        validateParameterNotNull(store, "Store must not be null");

        final Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        queryParams.put("customer", customerModel);
        queryParams.put("store", store);

        String filterClause = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(getFilterOrderStatusList()))
        {
            queryParams.put("filterStatusList", getFilterOrderStatusList());
            filterClause = FILTER_ORDER_STATUS;
        }

        final List<SortQueryData> sortQueries;

        if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(status))
        {
            queryParams.put("statusList", Arrays.asList(status));
            sortQueries = Arrays.asList(
                    createSortQueryData("byDate",
                            createQuery(FIND_ORDERS_BY_CUSTOMER_STORE_QUERY_AND_STATUS, filterClause, SORT_ORDERS_BY_DATE)),
                    createSortQueryData("byOrderNumber",
                            createQuery(FIND_ORDERS_BY_CUSTOMER_STORE_QUERY_AND_STATUS, filterClause, SORT_ORDERS_BY_CODE)));
        }
        else
        {
            sortQueries = Arrays
                    .asList(
                            createSortQueryData("byDate",
                                    createQuery(FIND_ORDERS_BY_CUSTOMER_STORE_QUERY, filterClause, SORT_ORDERS_BY_DATE)),
                            createSortQueryData("byOrderNumber",
                                    createQuery(FIND_ORDERS_BY_CUSTOMER_STORE_QUERY, filterClause, SORT_ORDERS_BY_CODE)));
        }
        }

        return getPagedFlexibleSearchService().search(sortQueries, "byDate", queryParams, pageableData);
    }

DefaultCustomerAccountService   getOrderList

public SearchPageData<OrderModel> getOrderList(final CustomerModel customerModel, final BaseStoreModel store,
            final OrderStatus[] status, final PageableData pageableData)
    {
        validateParameterNotNull(customerModel, "Customer model cannot be null");
        validateParameterNotNull(store, "Store must not be null");
        validateParameterNotNull(pageableData, "PageableData must not be null");
        return getCustomerAccountDao().findOrdersByCustomerAndStore(customerModel, store, status, pageableData);
    }

DefaultOrderFacade  getPagedOrderHistoryForStatuses

public SearchPageData<OrderHistoryData> getPagedOrderHistoryForStatuses(final PageableData pageableData,
            final OrderStatus... statuses)
    {
        final CustomerModel currentCustomer = (CustomerModel) getUserService().getCurrentUser();
        final BaseStoreModel currentBaseStore = getBaseStoreService().getCurrentBaseStore();
        final SearchPageData<OrderModel> orderResults = getCustomerAccountService().getOrderList(currentCustomer, currentBaseStore,
                statuses, pageableData);

        return convertPageData(orderResults, getOrderHistoryConverter());
    }

AccountPageController   orders
public String orders(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") final int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "show", defaultValue = "Page") final ShowMode showMode,
            @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) final String sortCode, final Model model) throws CMSItemNotFoundException
    {
        // Handle paged search results
        final PageableData pageableData = createPageableData(page, 5, sortCode, showMode);
        final SearchPageData<OrderHistoryData> searchPageData = vinOrderFacade.getPagedOrderHistoryForStatuses(pageableData);
        populateModel(model, searchPageData, showMode);

        storeCmsPageInModel(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(ORDER_HISTORY_CMS_PAGE));
        setUpMetaDataForContentPage(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(ORDER_HISTORY_CMS_PAGE));
        model.addAttribute(BREADCRUMBS_ATTR, accountBreadcrumbBuilder.getBreadcrumbs("text.account.orderHistory"));
        model.addAttribute(ThirdPartyConstants.SeoRobots.META_ROBOTS, ThirdPartyConstants.SeoRobots.NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW);
        model.addAttribute("isASM", assistedServiceFacade.isAssistedServiceAgentLoggedIn());
        return getViewForPage(model);
    }
```

Comment: You can enable flexquery debug log for getting SQL's. I think this line getting SQL: "LOG.debug(this.getInfoForLogging(executableQuery.getSQL(), limitBuilder.getModifiedStatement(), ...."

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

`FlexibleSearchService` this service is having API `TranslationResult translate(FlexibleSearchQuery arg0)` which you can use to convert your FlexibleSearchQuery to SQL Query.

For example :

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ExampleClass.class);

@Resource
private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService

......

FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query_string);
TranslationResult result = flexibleSearchService.translate(query);
LOG.info("SQL Query : " + result.getSQLQuery());
LOG.info("SQL Query Parameter : " + result.getSQLQueryParameters());
```

For more details, you can check its implementation in `DefaultFlexibleSearchService` class or check [this](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/41844/how-to-specialize-a-query-regarding-fetch-type.html)

Comment: deprecated now an throws exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test your flex search queries, see the SQL output and the result, you can do this from HAC -> Console -> Flexible Search. The interface is quite simple and useful.

If you want to get all the sql queries, you can go again to HAC -> Monitoring -> Database -> JDBC Logging.